# How can I pause and resume google TTS without synthesizing TTS into Audio in android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, resume, pause, google-text-to-speech

How can I pause and resume google TTS without synthesizing TTS into Audio in android Like media player play pause.

Comment: Be more specific, and provide more details about the issue you are facing

Comment: tts.speak("Hello gentalman", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null). when I call this method TTS start speak the text that I have provided but I want to pause TTS speak on button click and after pause I want to resume same text, start from where user pause it.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: @AyushMalviya I have done some calculation based on time. Like I assume that TTS will take 1 millisecond to speak 1 word So on this basis after speaking for 5 second then I assume that 5 words has been completed.
This will not a perfect solution for long strings.